# Python missing image

Tags: python, image, class, tkinter

So I want to create a window with a displayed image (from a specific file) and single button to close the window.
So far it shows the window, resizes the window to fit the the image, but doesn't show the image itself.
Here's what I have so far

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image
import ImageTk
class MyApp:                         
  def __init__(self, rData):
    self.cont1 = Frame(rData)
    self.cont1.pack(side="top", padx=5, pady=5)    
    self.button1 = Button(rData) 
    self.button1["text"]= "Exit"     
    self.button1["background"] = "red"      
    self.button1.pack(side="bottom",padx=5, pady=5, fill=X)                         
    self.button1["command"]= rData.destroy
    self.picture1 = Label(self.cont1)
    self.picture1["image"] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("fire.ppm"))
    self.picture1.pack(fill="both")  
root = Tk()
myapp = MyApp(root)  
root.mainloop()
```

When I wrote the same thing without making it into a class, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to keep your own reference to the `PhotoImage` you create, or python will garbage collect it, because Tkinter doesn't keep a reference to it.  This is either a bug or a feature, depending on your thinking.  This code should solve your problem:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image
import ImageTk
class MyApp:                         
  def __init__(self, rData):
    self.cont1 = Frame(rData)
    self.cont1.pack(side="top", padx=5, pady=5)    
    self.button1 = Button(rData) 
    self.button1["text"]= "Exit"     
    self.button1["background"] = "red"      
    self.button1.pack(side="bottom",padx=5, pady=5, fill=X)                         
    self.button1["command"]= rData.destroy
    self.picture1 = Label(self.cont1)
    self.photoImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("fire.ppm"))   # This line prevents your photo image from getting garbage collected.
    self.picture1["image"] = self.photoImage
    self.picture1.pack(fill="both")  
root = Tk()
myapp = MyApp(root)  
root.mainloop()
```