# Button image not appearing in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, osx-yosemite

I'm new to tkinter and am running python 3.4.2 with Tk version 8.5.17 using IDLE 3.4.2 under Yosemite. This is a modified demo from Liang's book *Introduction to Programming Using Python 3*. I was expecting the following code to display four buttons:

```
from tkinter import *

class ButtonsDemo:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Buttons Demo")

        frame0 = Frame(window)  
        frame0.pack()

        plusImage = PhotoImage(file = "image/plus.gif")
        minusImage = PhotoImage(file = "image/minus.gif")
        timesImage = PhotoImage(file = "image/times.gif")
        divideImage = PhotoImage(file = "image/divide.gif")

        Button(frame0, image = plusImage, command =
                 self.add).grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        Button(frame0, image = minusImage, command =
                 self.subtract).grid(row = 1, column =2)
        Button(frame0, image = timesImage, command =
                 self.multiply).grid(row = 1, column = 3)
        Button(frame0, image = divideImage, command =
                 self.divide).grid(row = 1, column = 4)
        window.mainloop()

    def add(self):
         print("add pressed")

    def subtract(self):
         print("subtract pressed")

    def multiply(self):
         print("multiply pressed")

    def divide(self):
         print("divide pressed")

ButtonsDemo()
```

When I run the code, only the first three buttons are displayed.  The button with divideImage on it does not appear.

If I click where the divide button should be, I do get the message "divide pressed".  It's as if the button is there, but it's invisible.

I see the same behavior running the program from the command line 
instead of from IDLE.

There's nothing wrong with the gif. If I use divide.gif for plusImage, I can see divide.gif in the first button position.  Also, when I put `text = "Divide"` on the divide button instead of `image = DivideImage`, the button becomes visible.

Why is the divide button invisible when I use an image?  How can I fix it?

EDIT:   Here's the code with everything moved to the main program.   I think this should have fixed a garbage collection problem if there were one.  Is this correct?

```
from tkinter import *

def add():
         print("add pressed")

def subtract():
     print("subtract pressed")

def multiply():
     print("multiply pressed")

def divide():
     print("divide pressed")


window = Tk()
window.title("Buttons Demo")
frame0 = Frame(window)  
frame0.pack()

plusImage = PhotoImage(file = "image/plus.gif")
minusImage = PhotoImage(file = "image/minus.gif")
timesImage = PhotoImage(file = "image/times.gif")
divideImage = PhotoImage(file = "image/divide.gif")

Button(frame0, image = plusImage, command =
             add).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
Button(frame0, image = minusImage, command =
             subtract).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
Button(frame0, image = timesImage, command =
             multiply).grid(row = 0, column = 2)

Button(frame0, image = divideImage, command =
             divide).grid(row = 0, column = 3)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me, but I do observe that you put the divide button in column 5 instead of column 4.

Comment: Same here. No problems with showing images.

Comment: and really your columns should be zero indexed

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Moving the divide button to column 4 didn't make a difference.  Fourth button is still invisible for me.

Comment: Rob and Marcin, what platform did you use to run the code?  Could my problem because I'm using yosemite?

Comment: @v_coelacanth python 3.4, ubuntu 14.04. Maybe the problem is not your code or platform, but image. Maybe 4th image is different or corrupted.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17436741/7432

Comment: @Marcin, changing all the images to the plus sign gif still gives an invisible button, but subbing a completely different (larger) gif makes the fourth button appear.   It could be that all the original gifs are corrupted in some way.  Or, is there possibly some kind of buffering issue going on?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley   I think moving everything out of the class should have fixed any garbage collection problem.  Is the right?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @v_coelacanth No. Assign each of the button's a variable. Even if it is just something like `Button1 = Button(...)`

Comment: @v_coelacanth: the core issue isn't classes, it's that the images are created as variables local to a function. It doesn't matter if it's a method or a regular function -- wherever they are created, the references must persist. But yes, if you move it out of the class and into the global space, that should be one solution to the problem.